# not show the record for which length has expired value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, redux

**update1**: I tried in sandbox there also its returning empty :( https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-https-u8lu2

- when I filter my starsValues with height and weight, I am getting the results.
- on top of that I should not show the record for which length has expired value, for this condition
- so I wrote the below condition inside my filter.
  `(searchFilter.length && !searchFilter.length[0].expired == 'Y') &&`
- but I am not getting the desired values.
- I tried to debug by putting consoles inside filter.
- but nothing helping me.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet below

```or-tag-here
filteredResult = nextprops.starsValues
                .filter(
                searchFilter =>

                   // (searchFilter.length && !searchFilter.length[0].expired == 'Y') &&
                    searchFilter.height === this.props.data.height &&
                    searchFilter.weight === this.props.data.weight
                // }
                )
                .map(search => {
                    console.log('search-->', search);
                    let spec = '';
                    let specialities = this.props.length.find(
                        page => page.homeId == search.homeId
                    );
                    if (specialities && specialities.specialties) {
                        spec = specialities.specialties;
                    }
                    //                        | ${search.length[0].number}

                    return {
                        label: `${search.fdfdgs}
                        | ${search.height}
                        | ${spec}
                        | ${search.weight}

                        `,
                        value: search.weight,
                        checked: true,
                    };
                });

[
  {
    "homeId": 434343,
    "fdds": 8063737,
    "rerefe": "154964746045100",
    "fsf": "2019-02-08 19:02:31",
    "height": "fddfdf",
    "sdsdds": "fd",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "fd",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "fd",
    "length": [
      {
        "number": "6767"
      }
    ],
    "refrefre": [
      {
        "number": "332322323"
      }
    ],
    "stth": [
      {
        "number": "l;l;;l",
        "expired": "Y"
      },
      {
        "number": "107125"
      },
      {
        "number": "323232"
      }
    ],
    "sortColumn": "6767"
  },
  {
    "homeId": 233232,
    "fdds": 8336007,
    "rerefe": "155410986184100",
    "fsf": "2019-04-01 19:01:54",
    "height": "rerere",
    "sdsdds": "gfdfgfg",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "gfdfgfg",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "gfdfgfg",
    "sortColumn": ""
  },
  {
    "homeId": 656,
    "fdds": 8519423,
    "rerefe": "155612474568800",
    "fsf": "2019-04-24 18:04:41",
    "height": "fddfdf",
    "sdsdds": "gfdfgfg",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "gfdfgfg",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "gfdfgfg",
    "length": [
      {
        "number": "119"
      }
    ],
    "refrefre": [
      {
        "number": "88998"
      }
    ],
    "stth": [
      {
        "number": "4063",
        "expired": "Y"
      },
      {
        "number": "100001"
      },
      {
        "number": "6819"
      }
    ],
    "sortColumn": "119"
  },
  {
    "homeId": 6565,
    "fdds": 8648222,
    "rerefe": "155677756668200",
    "fsf": "2019-05-02 19:05:49",
    "height": "fggfgffg",
    "sdsdds": "gfdfgfg",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "gfdfgfg",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "gfdfgfg",
    "length": [
      {
        "number": "6A0BO"
      }
    ],
    "refrefre": [
      {
        "number": "1851892467"
      }
    ],
    "sortColumn": "6A0BO"
  },
  {
    "homeId": 6556,
    "fdds": 7102392,
    "rerefe": "153216057385900",
    "fsf": "2018-07-21 06:07:27",
    "height": "fddfdf",
    "sdsdds": "8989898",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "8989898",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "8989898",
    "length": [
      {
        "number": "L8P"
      }
    ],
    "refrefre": [
      {
        "number": "1730277229"
      }
    ],
    "stth": [
      {
        "number": "088088008"
      },
      {
        "number": "105961"
      }
    ],
    "sortColumn": "L8P"
  },
  {
    "homeId": 4545,
    "fdds": 8663767,
    "rerefe": "155717411337700",
    "fsf": "2019-05-06 19:04:04",
    "height": "fddfdf",
    "sdsdds": "gfgfgfgf",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "gfgfgfgf",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "gfgfgfgf",
    "length": [
      {
        "number": "OM2"
      }
    ],
    "stth": [
      {
        "number": "4063",
        "expired": "Y"
      }
    ],
    "sortColumn": "OM2"
  },
  {
    "homeId": dfdffd,
    "fdds": 8336007,
    "rerefe": "155410986184100",
    "fsf": "2019-04-01 19:01:54",
    "height": "fddfdf",
    "sdsdds": "yuiuyuy",
    "weight": "8989989832",
    "weightType": "EIN",
    "fdfdgs": "yuiuyuy",
    "formattedweight": "89899889",
    "dfsf": "yuiuyuy",
    "length": [
      {
        "number": "4334",
        "expired": "Y"
      }
    ],
    "refrefre": [
      {
        "number": "6565"
      }
    ],
    "stth": [
      {
        "number": "3443"
      },
      {
        "number": "4343"
      }
    ],
    "sortColumn": "3443"
  }
]
```

Comment: can you try adding a verifiable code?

Comment: @karthick I tried in sandbox there also its returning empty :( https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-https-u8lu2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the expression:

```
(searchFilter.length && !searchFilter.length[0].expired == 'Y')
```

And specifically:

```
!searchFilter.length[0].expired == 'Y'
```

The order of operations will be:

1) evaluation of `searchFileter.length[0] // 'Y'`

2) negating this value `// false`

3) equating with `'Y'` `// false == 'Y' ====> false`

The fix will be to put the expression in parantheses and negating afterwards:

```
searchFilter.length && !(searchFilter.length[0].expired == 'Y')
```

Does that fix your problem?